# Coding guidelines for high nesting/parentheses

Tags: python, pep

Does python have any suggestions on how highly nested calls should look? For example, here is an example:

```
handler = SAXEventHandler(
            target=to_dict(
                target=dict_filter(key='title', value='Brown Christmas', 
                    target=dict_filter(key='vendor_id', value='02528_MLNA', 
                        target=print_me()
                    )
                )
            )
        )
```

Though it could also be:

```
handler = SAXEventHandler(
  target=to_dict(target=dict_filter(key='title', value='Brown Christmas', 
  target=dict_filter(key='vendor_id', value='02528_MLNA', target=print_me()))))
```

Or any number of variations. Are there guidelines with how this should be done with code similar to the above?

Comment: Did you look through [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)?

Comment: another option would be to use black, which will enforce a consistent style for this sort of thing (and other sorts of things) across your code. Even when I sometimes don't love the style, the most important thing is enforcing consistency everywhere. https://github.com/psf/black

Comment: @wwii -- sure, conceptually it makes sense, but there's no example more than one level of nesting in it -- if there is and I'm missing it could you please point out where?

Comment: @MaxPower -- very cool, I had never seen that before, thanks for mentioning that. Here's an example of the nesting with it: https://imgur.com/a/9lIEYkg.

Comment: @MaxPower here's a good one too: https://github.com/google/yapf

Comment: hey thanks, I'll definitely check that out!